# Alternative to TextIO

Tags: java, output

I had to print some Strings in a `TextTerminal` using the `TextIO` class and this code worked fine:

```
public class InOut {
    private final TextIO textIo;
    private final TextTerminal<?> textTerminal;

    public InOut() {
        textIo = TextIoFactory.getTextIO();
        textTerminal = textIo.getTextTerminal();
    }

    public void printLn(String output) {
        textTerminal.println(output);
    }
    ...
}
```

I however recently added ANSI escape sequences to the String I'm feeding in the `println` method, as when using `System.out.println` those sequences allowed text to be formatted. I however noticed that the `TextIO` does not read these sequences correctly and outputs them as text instead. Is there an alternative to ANSI escape sequences that will work with `TextIO` and `TextTerminal` or is there another class that I can use with the `TextTerminal` that will read ANSI escape sequences correctly?

The escape sequences I'm trying to use are `"\u001B[32m"` (print some green text) and `"\u001B[0m"` (reset the print color)

I forgot to add: ChatGPT proposed to use the `AnsiTextTerminal` class, so I searched for some documentation. I found this page: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.beryx/text-io/1.9.0/org/beryx/textio/jline/AnsiTextTerminal.html , however when I try to import the class with `import org.beryx.textio.jline.AnsiTextTerminal` as described on the javadoc page my IDE can't find the class

Comment: Hello and welcome. "my IDE can't find the class" did you download the appropriate jar and added it as a dependency?

Comment: where can I download it from? When I look at the javadoc I can only see the documentation, no download link.

Comment: by the way, thanks for the editing of my question. It's way more clear now with the code highlighted

Comment: The official website for Text IO looks like a good place to start. Both for downloads and for documentation. https://text-io.beryx.org/releases/latest/ The one you linked refers to version 1.9.0, while the current version is 3.4.1. `AnsiTextTerminal` doesn't seem to exist beyond version 1.9.0, and that's probably the reason your IDE can't find it (you're probably using a more recent version of Text IO). TL;DR: don't trust ChatGPT just yet.

Comment: About the edits, no problem, you're welcome ;)

Comment: found this: [link]https://github.com/beryx/text-io , but the class AnsiTextTerminal does not exist here (or at least that's what I found in this other documentation: [link]https://text-io.beryx.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/beryx/textio/jline/package-summary.html )

Comment: thanks for the reply! I'll search for some alternatives to TextIO than

Comment: Which TextTerminal ARE you using? I would expect `SystemTextTerminal` and potentially `ConsoleTextTerminal` to work in this case. Those basically just output to stdout so if the terminal emulator you are running in supports the sequences, then it should kind of just work?

Comment: I can try using these other Terminals, but if the solution I provided will work I may stick with it, as I should probably keep using the given classes (it's for an assignment), thanks for the advice anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution: TextTerminal temporary properties - ( from https://text-io.beryx.org/releases/latest/#terminal_temporary_props )**

> Sometimes you want to temporarily change some TextTerminal properties
> and revert them to their previous values after a couple of operations.
> You can achieve this by passing the sequence of operations to be
> executed with modified properties as argument to the
> `executeWithPropertiesConfigurator()` method, as shown in the example
> below.
>
> ```
> textTerminal.getProperties().setPromptColor("cyan");
> textTerminal.println("1. Choose the desired hard drive.");
> textTerminal.executeWithPropertiesConfigurator(
>         props -> props.setPromptColor("red"),
>         t -> t.println("2. Backup all your data."));
> textTerminal.println("3. Start the formatting process.");
> ```
>
> The second message will appear in red, while the other two will be
> printed in cyan.
>
> The code above uses hard-coded property values. A more elegant
> solution is to specify these values in the `textio.properties` file.
> TextTerminal offers the `executeWithPropertiesPrefix()` convenience
> method to help you accomplish this task.
>
> Consider the code below:
>
> ```
> textTerminal.println("1. Choose the desired hard drive.");
> textTerminal.executeWithPropertiesPrefix("warn",
>         t -> t.println("2. Backup all your data."));
> textTerminal.println("3. Start the formatting process.");
> ```
>
> and let’s assume that your textio.properties contains:
>
> ```
> textio.prompt.color = cyan
> textio.warn.prompt.color = red
> ```
>
> Then, the second message will appear in red, while the other two will
> be printed in cyan.

Comment: You're doing the correct thing by answering your own question, but link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.

Comment: Modified the answer in order to prevent information loss when the linked page will be deleted or the link modified